# How to get creation time of indices in elastic search using Jest

Tags: elasticsearch, exchangewebservices, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to delete the indexes from elasticsearch which are created 24 hours before. I am not finding a way to get the creation time of indices for the particular node. Using spring boot elastic search, this can be accomplished. However, I am using the Jest API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `settings.index.creation_date` value that was stored at index creation time.

With curl you can get it easily using:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_settings
```

You get:

```
{
  "your_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1460663685415",   <--- this is what you're looking for
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1040599"
        },
        "uuid" : "dIG5GYsMTueOwONu4RGSQw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With Jest, you can get the same value using:

```
    import io.searchbox.indices.settings.GetSettings;

    GetSettings getSettings = new GetSettings.Builder().build();
    JestResult result = client.execute(getSettings);
```

You can then use `JestResult` in order to find the `creation_date`

If I may suggest something, [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) would be a much handier tool for achieving what you need.

Simply run this once a day:

```
curator delete indices --older-than 1 --time-unit days
```

Comment: can you elaborate on client().admin() , Iam unable to get it, through JestClient.thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have to use Jest Client absolutely.

Comment: can you tell me how to use curator

Comment: Simply install it (check the link I shared) and then run the command I gave you above.

Comment: Thanks _@Val_, I got it. I will get back if I have any issues.

Comment: Can you suggest me, how many master nodes and data nodes, and replication is well enough for the production environment? @Val

Comment: It ultimately depends on your data and use cases.